# Automatically rebase only when pulling from upstream branch

Tags: git, git-branch

Let's say I have two remotes: `parent` (not called `upstream` here to avoid confusion) and `origin` (fork of `parent`) and the `master` branch has `origin/master` as upstream, so that I can pull from `parent/master` and `origin/master` and only push to `origin/master`. It seems reasonable to want pulls from `origin/upstream` to use `rebase` (since any commits this would rewrite aren't pushed anywhere). But pulls from `parent/master` shouldn't rebase, since they couldn't be pushed to `origin/master` without rewriting history. However, if I set `pull.rebase` to true in Git config, it makes pulls from both use rebase. Is it possible to set up Git the way I want? Or is there a reason this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to stick my neck out and claim there's no setting that will allow you to do this automatically (i.e. no per-remote equivalent of `pull.rebase`).

One approach would be to set up aliases so you can do `git pullparent` and `git pullorigin` or whatever you decide to call them.

In fact, you might be able to get really clever and re-alias `git pull` so that it passes the correct flags based on the other parameters, but completely new command names might be less WTFey in the long run.